# Remove script if viewport is mobile

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I am working with Skrollr.js. As it turns out, this library does not work on iOS mobile. I can get everything to look fine on both mobile and other media queries, however, it only works on mobile when I remove:

```
<script src="shared_javascript/skrollr.js" id="remove_me_on_mobile"></script>
```

When I remove the script, everything works on mobile but will not work on other media queries.

I tried this:

```
    var script = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");

    if (script.matches) {
        $('.fill_in').html('<script src="shared_javascript/skrollr.js" id="remove_me_on_mobile"></script>')
    }
```

Where my index.html is:

```
<div class='fill_in'></div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In skrollr.js check navigator object to know if it is mobile and return; ie `if(navigator.someproperty tells it is mobile) return;` and you are done

Comment: it does work on any device, but it causes too much lag as i know

Comment: You're getting errors because you've got the string `</script>` in the middle of your code. It should look like this: `<\/script>`

Comment: You can add script if is not a mobile...

Comment: Thanks all. Pointy's suggestion solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append the script if the screen size is larger than a mobile screen would be (realistically though, you can put any conditional you like in the if to validate if it is mobile or not).

```
$(function(){
    if($('body').width() > 400) { $('head').append('<script src="shared_javascript/skrollr.js" id="remove_me_on_mobile"><\/script>'); }
});
```

Comment: Not working in my case I want to remove scrollify.js if loaded in mobile.